# SSAS :Role Driven Security

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I hope you are doing well.

It's about Role Driven Dynamic Security.
And I would like to have your opinion.
I am working on a tabular model deployed on Azure Analysis Service.
I need to implement role-based security rules.
All security roles are based on AD groups, not users.
So I decided to implement the role driven security.

--> I created a mapping table [Sec_PortfolioRole] between roles and PortFolio.
Each role must be able to filter the Portfolios assigned to it.
Here is the table:
[image]

--> In SSDT's Manager Role, I created the 2 roles as in the image:

[image]

--> There is a relationship between the Dim_PortFolio (PortFolio_key) and the fact table (Measures_Holdings)
I put the filter rule on the Fact table (Holdings).
The AGFACB role should therefore only see the data of the PortFolio_Key = 'AGFACB'

I don't understand why it doesn't work.:-(
Did I miss something?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would assume creating the permission on the dimension table is more logical. If you add your DAX Filter on the Dim_PortFolio does it work as you expect ?